# Find out if system (Windows) was booted with BIOS or UEFI with Python 3

Tags: python, windows, bios, uefi

How do I find out if Windows was booted with UEFI or BIOS with Python?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this website](https://itsfoss.com/check-uefi-or-bios/#windows), you can do something like that:

- *Alternative 1:* Reading a command output

```py
import subprocess

out = subprocess.check_output(['bcdedit']).decode('utf-8')

is_loader = False
for line in out.split('\n'):
    # Ignore lines until the Windows Boot Loader section
    if not is_loader and 'Windows Boot Loader' in line:
        is_loader = True

    if not is_loader:
        continue

    # Ignore lines until the path subsection
    if not line.startswith('path'):
        continue
    
    # Receives 'EXE' (BIOS) or 'EFI' (UIEF)
    boot_type = line[-3:].upper()
    
    # You can also use an if-else expression
    # Receives 'BIOS' or 'UIEF'
    # boot_type = 'BIOS' if line[-3:] == 'exe' else 'UIEF'
```

- *Alternative 2*: Reading a log file

```py
import re

with open(r'C:\Windows\Panther\setupact.log') as f:
    pattern = re.compile(r'Detected boot environment: (\w+)')

    # Iterate over every line of file until finds a match
    for line in f:
        match = pattern.search(line)
        if match:
            # Receives 'BIOS' or 'UEFI'
            boot_type = match.group(1).upper()
            break
```